# Finding Where a Filename is Used in Django

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I am currently working on a project in Django (1.9) and used a filename convention that was suitable for my needs. Such a need was rebuilding the entire site using Django, and using the same filenames but with 'django_' in front.

Example: `home.py` became `django_home.py`

Not that this explanation or example is necessary, just wanted everyone to see just what I am talking about. Anywho, I am now done transitioning over to Django and want to get rid of the `django_` in front of the filenames.

**Question**: How can I see what functions are using my filenames? I am currently using Atom as my IDE, maybe that has a tool? I can manually go through all my files and see what is affected (change names and see what comes up as an error in the dev server?) but I would love a more autonomous way of doing this.

Comment: Try searching in all files of your project. In Atom you can do it pressing `ctrl+shift+f`

Comment: WHOA. I overlooked such a simple tool... Thanks Carlos! Edit: I would like to point out though that this does not show me what filenames have this naming convention, that search only shows me what line inside what files that string appears. Still good enough for my current predicament!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ctrl+shift+f in atom.

Additionally, if you're using linux you can use the command in the root of your project:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec sed -i 's/django_//g' {} \;
```

That will get all python files in your project and remove the `django_` prefix from occurances found in those files. If you want to specify a folder replace the `.` after `find` by the folder name.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, a concise answer that takes care of just what I need.